# How to align equations in enumerate

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I want to do this, where the first and second equations in every line are aligned.
[image: 1]

So I tried by using `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, enumitem, blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $f_x = 4x^3y^3+16xy$,
            \item $f_x = -\pi \mathrm{e}^{-t}\sin{\pi x}$,
            \item $z_x = 20(2x+3y)^9$,
        
            $f_y = 3x^4y^2+8x^2$.
        
            $f_t = -e^{-t}\cos{\pi x}$.
        
            $z_y = 30(2x+3y)^9$.
        \end{multicols}
        \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The result is ok-ish, but the distance between the 2 columns is so large, and I have to write the content of the first column before writing the content of the second one.

I also tried by using `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, enumitem, blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1. & $f_x = 4x^3y^3+16xy$,                    & $f_y = 3x^4y^2+8x^2$.       \\
        2. & $f_x = -\pi \mathrm{e}^{-t}\sin{\pi x}$, & $f_t = -e^{-t}\cos{\pi x}$. \\
        3. & $z_x = 20(2x+3y)^9$,                     & $z_y = 30(2x+3y)^9$.
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \addtocounter{enumi}{3}
        \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which solves the latter 2 problems, but makes numering becomes a manual thing, and the numbers aren't aligned.

Is there a (simpler) way to do so with the distance between the 2 columns not be too large and/or in a convenient way that is writing the content row by row instead of column by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox, enumitem, blindtext}

\newcommand{\enumeqboxes}[3]{%
  % #1 = label, #2 = math material left, #3 = math material right
  \eqmakebox[#1@1][l]{$#2$,}\quad\eqmakebox[#1@2][l]{$#3$.}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \enumeqboxes{A}{f_x = 4x^3y^3+16xy}{f_y = 3x^4y^2+8x^2}

\item \enumeqboxes{A}{f_x = -\pi e^{-t}\sin(\pi x)}{f_t = -e^{-t}\cos(\pi x)}

\item \enumeqboxes{A}{z_x = 20(2x+3y)^9}{z_y = 30(2x+3y)^9}

\item \blindtext

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The first argument is an arbitrary label, which should be different for every usage of the trick. So, with another group of formulas, you'll use, say, `B`, and so on.

[image]

Note: I fixed `\sin{\pi x}` into `\sin(\pi x)` and also the inconsistency in the typesetting of the constant *e*: either always upright or always italic (better, in my opinion).